# Why doesn't my column float to the left edge of my container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I want to make two rows with 3 thumb nail pictures on each row.  I'm using Bootstrap.  The container is 960px with 20px gutters, so 940px wide.  I've included my CSS and HTML code. What am I doing wrong?  I've been struggling with this for some time.
CSS Code:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; src: url(../fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf); }

body { border-top:10px solid #fb6938; }
header { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
header h1 a { display: block; width: 172px; height: 25px; background: url(../img/Logo.png) no-repeat; }
header h1 { margin: 26px 24px 28px 0; }
header h2 {font-weight: normal !important; margin-top: 28px; line-height: 25px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-size: 14px; color: #7b7b7b; }
header ul { list-style-type: none;}

nav a { display: inline-block; padding: 0 9px; border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5; border-left: 2px solid #e5e5e5; font: italic 14px Georgia, serif; }
nav ul { margin: 0;}
nav ul.list-inline li { padding: 0; line-height: 79px;}
nav ul :first-child a { border: none; }
nav ul :last-child a { border: none; }

footer { padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px; border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
footer nav a { font: normal 11px Arial, sans-serif; }
footer nav ul.list-inline li { line-height: 25px; }

section h1 { font-family: Georgia; font-size: 30px; font-style: italic; color: #000; line-height: 42px; }
img { border-bottom: 10px solid; color: #fb6938; }
section li { color: #ff6b39; }
article { padding-bottom: 30px; border-top: 5px solid #eee;}
article.intro { border-top: none; border-bottom: 5px solid #eee; }

ul.thumbnails { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
li.thumbnail:first-child { padding-left: 0px !important;  }
li.thumbnail:nth-child(4) { padding-left: 0px !important; }
li.thumbnail:nth-child(4) { margin-bottom: 39px; }
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <hgroup class="clearfix col-sm-8">
           <h1 class="pull-left"><a class="text-hide " href="/" title="visit the Mumbo home page">Mumbo!</a></h1>
           <h2 class="pull-left">Powered by Jeffrey Way Industries</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
     </div>
   </div>
    </header>
<section role="main">
  <div class ="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-md-8">Take a look at our work to see what we mean</h1>
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Vimeo">Vimeo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Last.fm">Last.fm</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Dribbble">Dribbble</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
        </div>
        <img alt="A big image!" src="img/hero.png" />
        <article class="intro">
            <h1>Risus portacon vestibulum posuere</h1>
            <div class="row">
            <p class="col-md-8">Cray sustainable <a href="#" title="A link!"> vegan post-ironic</a> mixtape. 8-bit sustainable sed put a bird on it keytar fingerstache et, ennui street art proident wayfarers viral ethnic. Eu craft beer anim, keffiyeh chambray occaecat jean shorts hella selvage keytar butcher vice in. American apparel pour-over master cleanse, fingerstache etsy qui umami dreamcatcher twee.</p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#" title="A link">Cray sustainable vegan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="A link">Chambray occaecat jean shorts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="A Link">Hella selvage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="A link">Over master cleanse</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
                </div>
        </article>
    <h1>Take a look at our work to see what we mean</h1>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
              <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb1.png"/>
            <h2>Purus Egestas Fusce</h2>
                <p>
                    Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                    egestas eget quam.
                </p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
            <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb2.png"/>
            <h2>Purus Egestas Fusce</h2>
            <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                egestas eget quam.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
              <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb3.png"/>
            <h2>Purus Egestas Fusce</h2>
            <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                egestas eget quam.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
            <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb4.png"/>
            <h2>
                Purus Egestas Fusce </h2>
            <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                egestas eget quam.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
                <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb5.png"/>
                <h2>Purus Egestas Fusce</h2>
                <p>
                    Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                    egestas eget quam.
                </p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 thumbnail text-center">
                <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb6.png"/>
            <h2>Purus Egestas Fusce</h2>
            <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
                egestas eget quam.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
<article>
    <h1>Ornare Tristique Adipiscing Dolor</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-md-8">C ray sustainable vegan post-ironic mixtape. 8-bit sustainable sed put a bird on it keytar fingerstache et, ennui street art proident wayfarers viral ethnic. Eu craft beer anim, keffiyeh chambray occaecat jean shorts hella selvage keytar butcher vice in. American apparel pour-over master cleanse, fingerstache etsy qui umami dreamcatcher twee.</p>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="#" title="A link">Cray sustainable vegan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="A link">Chambray occaecat jean shorts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="A link">Hella selvage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="A link">Over master cleanse</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
</div>
</section>
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <small class="col-md-8">&copy; 2012 All Rights Reserved. Powered by Jeffrey Way Industries</small>
    <nav class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

design should look like this:
[image]

Changes to the code and the result in inspector:
[image]

Comment: I threw your code into a fiddle and it's working https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/pdcdnc0w/1/. Are your images different sizes?

Comment: No, I checked them in photoshop.   All the images are 300 X 215 px. (W X H )

Comment: Ah I posted this below also, but when the images are loaded in the browser and I inspect them, they are actually different sizes.  How do I constrain them to the same size as the browser size changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what the issue is without the images, but one issue could be the images are coming back as different sizes. If this is the case, I would do the following:

Wrap the images in a div with a given class:

```
<div class = "img-container">
    <img alt="A thumbnail" src="img/thumb1.png" class = "my-image"/>
</div
```

Make the div's width whatever percentage you want the inner img to be and hide any overflow:

```
.img-container{
  width: 100%; /*Change this to whatever width you want*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Make the img's width 100%:

```
.my-image{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/pdcdnc0w/3/

Comment: Didn't work :(.  I did the changes in chrome developer too.  I'll add a picture of the changes to the main question.

Comment: I did make these changes to the .thumbnail class in the bootstrap css file:  

`.thumbnail{display:block; /* padding-top:1px */;margin-bottom:25px;line-height:1.78571429;background-color:#fff;/* border:1px solid #ddd */;border-radius:4px;/* -webkit-transition:border .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:border .2s ease-in-out;transition:border .2s ease-in-out */}`

Comment: Actually you know what although the thumbnails are all 300 X 215, it seems like the browser is altering the size of the jpeg images in response to the size of the browser.  In actuality, for whatever, reason the jpeg are actually different sizes.

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle. Let me know if this solves the issue

Comment: Yep! Awesome.  Wrapping the image with the image container div did the trick.